# Is java BigQuery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest) thread safe?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several threads each of which prepares its own `InsertAllRequest` but shares the same `BigQuery`. When the threads run concurrently, will `BigQuery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest)` cause problems?

Comment: Which programming language? Which library?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that we use java, use google-cloud-bigquery jar version 1.43.0. Basically we are streaming massive data to bigquery. thanks

Comment: You should take into account, at least, the streaming insert quota in BigQuery. Check my answer about it =)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no issue with InsertAll for java 1.43.0 version and streaming jobs could be performed concurrently. Therefore, you should be able to run concurrently different `BigQuery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest)` in java without problem. However, you should take into account [quota about streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts) in BigQuery. For example, you should not exceeded the maximum rows per second (per project and per table) or maximum bytes per second (per table).

Comment: does this also hold true for the python library (0.31.0 and higher)?

Comment: It worked for me with [BigQuery Python client library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/index.html) version 1.6.0.