# Is BigQuery java api thread safe?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I would like to use BigQuery java api 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery' in our project. I am creating service instance like this

```
BigQuery bq =
        BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .build()
            .getService();
```

Should I store this com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery instance somewhere in the app and reuse it for every call? Is it thread safe? What is the recommended way?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is java BigQuery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest) thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917463/is-java-bigquery-insertallinsertallrequest-thread-safe)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. That question is about particular method of the service. I would like to know in general if the service is fully thread safe. Should I keep in mind any limitations for other methods of this service class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest having this as a global variable and reuse it as you may hit a rate limit due to multiple authentication requests. Moreover, if you plan use Threads, I suggest checking the [BigQuery API quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#all_api_requests) to consider them in your development.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very helpful!